# Jquery Like AutoCompleteExtender In C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, linq, entity-framework-5

I am trying to make my Ajax AutoCompleteExtender look like this - 
http://jquery-sew.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/.
The suggestion list would show the code and its name in brackets. 
eg: C01 (Sweden). When an Item is selected, only the code will display in the textbox.

With help from here, I was able to get the suggestion list load with two concatenated names. And now stuck with the last part.

The idea is to get a postback done on item select and then perform string remove actions at server side. Is this correct.

**EDIT:**

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function itemSelected(source, eventArgs) {            
    var hdnID = document.getElementById('<%= hdnValue.ClientID %>');    
    hdnID.value = eventArgs.get_value();
    __doPostBack(hdnId, "");
}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:hiddenfield id="hdnValue" onvaluechanged="hdnValue_ValueChanged" runat="server"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="ace" runat="server" TargetControlId="txtSearch" 
 MinimumPrefixLength="2" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="10"  
 CompletionInterval="0" ServiceMethod="GetCodes" UseContextKey="True"
 CompletionListCssClass="autoComplete"
 CompletionListItemCssClass="autoCompleteItem"   
 CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autoCompleteHL"
 onclientitemselected="itemSelected">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

ASPX.CS:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string[] GetCodes(string prefixText)
 {
   CountryBLL objCountry = new CountryBLL();
   return objDAL.GetCodes(prefixText);
 }

protected void hdnValue_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   //perform string remove action.
 }
```

The postback is not hapening here unfortunately.

Comment: do you have issue with jquery plug-in or c# code ?

Comment: Its just that I dont know jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it as mentioned below as well :

```
public string[] GetCodes(string prefixText)
{
  return MyDB.tblCountries.Where(country=>country.CountryCode.
         StartsWith(prefixText)).OrderBy(country=>country.CountryCode).Select(country => country.CountryCode + "(" + country.CountryName + ")").ToArray();    
}
```

**Update :**

For the second part you can update your textbox **'txtSearch'** as shown below :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" onchange="ManageText(this); "></asp:TextBox>
```

and create new javascript method for the **ManageText** as mentioned below :

```
function ManageText(textControl) {
            textControl.value = textControl.value.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved my first part. Could you please advice about the next part I have mentioned.

Comment: can you post your design page with jquery ?

Answer (score 1):

you can have string[] using Linq as below

```
    public string[] GetCodes(string prefixText)
    {
      return MyDB.tblCountries.Where(c=>c.CountryCode.
             StartsWith(prefixText)).OrderBy(c=>c.CountryCode).Select(c=> c.CountryCode + "(" + c.CountryName + ")").ToArray();    
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved my first part. Could you please advice about the next part I have mentioned.